# PHP : CSV to array

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I have the following csv

[image: CSV formate]

And i want to convert it like :

```
$data = array(
 'firstName[0]' => 'test1',
 'lastName[0]' => 'test1',
 'email[0]' => 'test1@gmail.com'
 'firstName[1]' => 'test2',
 'lastName[1]' => 'test2',
 'email[1]' => 'test2@gmail.com'
 ...
 ...
);
```

The following code gives me a nested array and each row have an index in that array,

```
$csvData = file_get_contents('filename.csv');
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}
```

Output :

[image: Output]

which is in my case wrong, How will i be able to achieve that ?

Comment: Iterate your array and build a new one.

Comment: For closers - OP needs format of array which is __distinct__ form the one, get by `str_getcsv` and similar.

Comment: I think your understanding of array structure is wrong. To get the data from the array that you want, you'd have to use `$data['firstName[0]']`. To get the data as `$data['firstName'][0]`, then you'd need to have it as `$data = array( 'firstName' => array( 0=>'test1'));`.

Comment: @u_mulder Basically the OP need to write some code rather than hope that mashing a few built in functions can do it all for them

Comment: You should have a look at the Collection class in Laravel, which can help you transform your data

Comment: @aynber the columns can be 3 and also can be 25 so i cannot hard code that.

Comment: So you have to read the first line. Use the titles as names in an Assoc Array. Then read all other rows into the dynamic array

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes mate, Look for the example in question.

Comment: Possibly if you showed us a little more code we would better understand what the data is you are processing

Comment: @RiggsFolly question updated.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will help you

```
public function importCsv()
{
    $file = public_path('upload/test.csv');

    $customerArr = $this->csvToArray($file);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($customerArr); $i ++)
    {
    //   $customerArr[$i];
       //get data and insert or you ca use
    }

     print_r($customerArr);

}


function csvToArray($filename = '', $delimiter = ',')
{
    if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return false;

    $header = null;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== false)
        {
            if (!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('filename.csv'));

for ($j = 1; $j < count($csv); $j++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($csv[0]); $i++) {
        $myArray[$csv[0][$i].$j] = $csv[$j][$i];
    }
}

print_r($myArray);
```

Not the most elegant solution but will work for you. I used `for` loops so i can use their counters easier. The output result is :

```
Array
(
    [firstName1] => test1
    [lastName1] => Test1
    [email1] => test1@gmail.com
    [firstName2] => test2
    [lastName2] => Test2
    [email2] => test2@gmail.com
)
```

And my csv file looked like this:

```
firstName,lastName,email
test1,Test1,test1@gmail.com
test2,Test2,test2@gmail.com
```

The first loop starts the counter from position 1 so i avoid the headers, and will loop around the main csv array.

The nested loop will go through each of the nested arrays and based on the 1st one that holds the header info will concatenate the new key fields and create your new array.

If you want to have it **exactly** like in your example, with the brackets and the counter to start from 0 for the key field then you can simple:

```
<?php
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('filename.csv'));

for ($j = 1; $j < count($csv); $j++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($csv[0]); $i++) {
        $counter = $j-1;
        $myArray[$csv[0][$i].'['.$counter.']'] = $csv[$j][$i];
    }
}

print_r($myArray);
```

Which will output for you an array just like you requested in your question:

```
Array
(
    [firstName[0]] => test1
    [lastName[0]] => Test1
    [email[0]] => test1@gmail.com
    [firstName[1]] => test2
    [lastName[1]] => Test2
    [email[1]] => test2@gmail.com
)
```